# CSS Dropdown issue with IE 7

Tags: html, css, wordpress, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I have recently built this site with through wordpress and seem to be having some alignment issues with Internet Explorer 7.

Basically they appaering about 20 or so pixel's to the right and wondered what way to fix this? This has had me stumped for a while now and I feel like I am slowly running out of idea's.

Here is the link:

http://alleanza.co.uk

Is a screenshot needed? If so I ca post the one from the client later tonight, but It is only IE 7!?

The PHP and Html Structure I have for the list's is this:

```
<ul id="nav" class="clearfloat">
<li style="padding:10px 10px 0px 10px; height:20px; display:block;"><a href="http://www.alleanza.co.uk">Alleanza</a></li>
<div id="navoption"><ul><?php wp_list_pages('title_li='); ?></li></ul></div>
</ul>
```

Is that the correct structure? All help is appreciated..

Comment: Use a CSS reset and move your styling from your LI to your A-tag.

Comment: I have a method, but you have to edit the `<?php wp_list_pages('title_li='); ?>`. Is it possible?

Comment: If it is only IE7 and you are towards the end of the development cycle, just target that element with the start hack in your style sheet. *margin-right: -20px !important;

Answer (score 0):

You're nesting a div within your top-level `ul` menu item and that is probably what is breaking your design in IE7, surprised it even works in the other browsers:

```
<ul class="clearfloat" id="nav">
    <li>Alleanza</li>
    <div id="navoption"> <ul> ... </ul> </div>
</ul>
```

List items have to be nested within your menu list.

So wrap that div inside a list item and it should work:

```
<ul id="nav" class="clearfloat">
    <li style="padding:10px 10px 0px 10px; height:20px; display:block;"><a href="http://www.alleanza.co.uk">Alleanza</a></li>
    <li><div id="navoption"><ul><?php wp_list_pages('title_li='); ?></li></ul></div></li>
</ul>
```

**Note:** Noticed that you're using wordpress, you can actually create that "Alleanza" link right within the Menu's "custom link" option so you don't need to hardcode it in.

Documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_Screen

Comment: I have tried this but it is still not working? Cannot work out why!? I had left this question as I figured I could try using it on my own, but still no luck, any ideas?